The on-screen keyboard program has a focus issue
I'm trying to develop this code to use while coding, since the on-screen keyboard is not working, for easier access to characters like ( ) [ ] { }. However, when I click on the interface of the code, the cursor disappears and the program becomes non-functional. I can't solve this problem, please help me.
How does the program work properly as an on-screen keyboard?
https://github.com/iNezXuS/on-screen-keyboard/blob/main/main.py

Please post a [mre] here, not a link to an external site.
